# jTextFIeld bottom line border only

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm wanting to create a jTextField that only has a bottom black line for a border in the simplest way possible. createLineborder doesn't seem to have a parameter for only the bottom line. createEmptyBorder has but obviously no line.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
jTextField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0,0,1,0, Color.BLACK));
```